# How to capture variables for async functions in a coffeescript loop?

Tags: javascript, loops, coffeescript

I am looping over an object and trying to add an `onclick` event for each button that corresponds to each item in the object.

```
for id of obj
    button = $("#my_button"+ id)
    button.click(->  console.log id)
```

With this loop, ***every*** button logs the ***last*** id of the loop.  How do I get each button to log the proper corresponding id?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's a classic JavaScript problem. The standard solution is to wrap each loop iteration in an anonymous function, and pass `id` in to that function; that way, the function you're passing to `click` will see that particular `id` instance.

CoffeeScript provides a nice syntax for this purpose: `do (id) -> ...` compiles to `(function(id){ ... })(id)`. So, for your example, you'd write

```
for id of obj
  do (id) ->
    button = $("#my_button"+ id)
    button.click(->  console.log id)
```

I talk about `do` in my article [A CoffeeScript Intervention](http://pragprog.com/magazines/2011-05/a-coffeescript-intervention).